# get the values for each line in the file in c

Tags: c, file, scanf, readfile

I need to read this main.txt file:

```
STUDENT ID 126345
TEACHER MATH CLASS 122
```

And i need to get each values from this file . If this main.txt file was like this:

```
STUDENT ID 126345
TEACHER ID 3654432
```

I could do it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    FILE *ptr_file;

    int id;
    char string1[100],string2[100];
    ptr_file = fopen("main.txt","r");

    while(fscanf(ptr_file,"%s %s %d",string1,string2,id) != EOF){
       }
    }
```

But I can't use `fscanf()` function because space amount between these values is not equal for each line. How can i get every value in line by line like this code ?

Comment: The `id` argument should be `&id`, because you have to pass a pointer to `int`.

Comment: @okydoky please don't correct the code posted after comments unless it wasn't the original code. This is not a dynamic "correct-me" site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If every line has 3 values separated by empty spaces (or tabs), then

```
fscanf(ptr_file,"%s %s %d",string1,string2,&id);
```

is OK (and note that I used `&id` instead of `id`), because `%s` matches a sequence of non-white-space characters, so it
doesn't matter how many empty spaces are between the values, `%s` will consume
the empty spaces:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *v = "STUDENT  \t  ID   \t  126345";
    int id; 
    char string1[100],string2[100];

    sscanf(v, "%s %s %d", string1, string2, &id);
    printf("'%s' '%s' %d\n", string1, string2, id);
    return 0;
}
```

which prints

```
$ ./a 
'STUDENT' 'ID' 126345
```

In general the most robost solution would be to read line by line with `fgets`
and parse the line with `sscanf` as you have more control over when a line has a
wrong format:

```
char buffer[1024];
while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin))
{
    int id; 
    char string1[100],string2[100];
    if(sscanf(buffer, "%99s %99s %d", string1, string2, &id) != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Line with wrong format\n");
        break;
    }

    // do something with read values
}
```

**edit**

User [Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49266743/get-the-values-for-each-line-in-the-file-in-c/49266841#comment85537121_49266841) points out that the line might have 3 or 4 values, then you
could do this:

```
char buffer[1024];
while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin))
{
    int id; 
    char string1[100],string2[100],string3[100];
    res = sscanf(buffer, "%99s %99s %99s %d", string1, string2, string3, &id);

    if(res != 4)
    {
        int res = sscanf(buffer, "%99s %99s %d", string1, string2, &id);

        if(res != 3)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Line with wrong format, 3 or 4 values expected\n");
            break;
        }
    }


    if(res == 3)
        printf("'%s' '%s' %d\n", string1, string2, id);
    else
        printf("'%s' '%s' '%s' %d\n", string1, string2, string3, id);

}
```

Comment: Three values was hypothetical which OP knew how to do. The actual inputs have 3 or 4 fields.

Comment: @WeatherVane right, one line of the example has 4 values, fixed my answer

Comment: err.. should you try 4 values first?

Comment: @WeatherVane I guess I could, but does that make any difference in this case?

Comment: Yes, because if 4 values are entered, reading 3 with `sscanf` will be successful, and the 4th will be missed. So test for 4 values first, if that fails test for 3 values. You got upvotes, but seem to miss the question.

Comment: @WeatherVane oh yes, I didn't thought about the case `"ABC DEF 1 2"` where both `sscanf` would return 3 and 4. Thanks, I changed the order.

Comment: My comments were not entirely correct, since an alpha string would have failed the `%d` format. But still better this way round.

Comment: @WeatherVane that was what I was thinking at the beginning, if `sscanf` returns 4 then because there were 3 strings before the int, that's why I started with the 3 arguments call first. But I agree, doing the 4 argument first is better.